In MMSTV Is there an option to invert the meaning of RTS when using it for PTT?
I have an FTDI cable, whose RTS is connected through an opto isolator to my PTT. When I connect it to a Windows PC and run MMSSTV, it works, but it's inverted (PTT is on when not sending and off when sending).
My reason for asking is that if I flick over to Linux, I use QSSTV, which gives me the option of +RTS or -RTS which (I presume) would invert the meaning of the output.
Certainly, I could modify my PCB to sink the PTT rather than sourcing it. That's an easy fix, and is well within the novelty of the Ham ethos, but it would be a nice, lazy solution if someone said "yeah, just tick the Invert RTS checkbox!"

It seems to me that this question is so similar to your other one (only the software is different?) that they could be combined. If so, one of your questions might be closed as a duplicate.

The other is almost certainly a Linux configuration question. Although there may be something specific about QSSTV which one of the specialists will know. Whereas this one is a yes / no question on MSSTV. I hope you find them significantly different in this light! Advice on how to reword gratefully accepted!

No. there is not presently any such option in the software.
Problem: Rather than using RTS to drive the PTT directly, I've implemented an optocoupler. The RTS sits high normally, and gets pulled low when the software wants to Tx. Normally, pulling the PTT low would cause a Tx, but in this case, it switches the emitter of the optocoupler off, which allows the PTT to float high. So, when the software Txes the PTT if off. When the software stops Txing, the PTT becomes pressed.
Solution: in order to re-invert the output, instead of connecting the optocoupler between RTS and Gnd, to connect it between +3V3 and RTS. The net result is that when TRS is high, there is no potential difference, so the optcoupler output is off.... and vice-versa.
